# Visual studio customized snippet not shown on suggestions bar

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets

I have a code snippet I made and I want to use it during writing code,
the problem is that the Inteli-sense not suggest the snippet I made even though
I can see it was added as expected in the snippet manager window.

the snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
  <Header>
     <Title>xvar</Title>
     <Author>Michael Gabbay</Author>
     <Shortcut>xv</Shortcut>
     <Description>Expand a variable lambda expression</Description>
     <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
     </SnippetTypes>
  </Header>
<Snippet>
    <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[(x=> x)
                        ]]>
    </Code>
 </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Here you can see it was loaded successfully:

[image]

My expected result was to see the suggestion as described below:

[image]

Note - I'm using Vs2022.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code and there is no problem.
Did you do something wrong?
Did you try to restart the compiler?

[image]

### 1.

[image]

[image]

### 2. Tools->Code Snippets Manager

Click import:

[image]

### 3. Output:

[image]

### My version:

[image]

Best Regards,

Jiale

Comment: Restart compiler and reimport made it work